# TFS (web) gives error when building Typescript. TypeScript.targets not found

Tags: tfs, typescript, tfsbuild, azure-devops

We just converted our javascript files to typescript. Everything builds locally just fine but our build in TFS (cloud version i.e. tfs.visualstudio.com) gave us the error:

```
The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets"
 was not found. Confirm that the path in the declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

Locally we are using typescript version 0.9.1.1 and VS2012

And advise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To ensure that Web projects using Microsoft.TypeScript.targets will build successfully on a build server, you have two options:

1. Install TypeScript on the build server
2. Copy the required files for    Microsoft.TypeScript.targets to a different source-controlled folder and change the path references in
   the csproj file to this folder.

More details here => http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1518

Comment: Following the links from the one that suresh2 posted. It seems that the problem has been opened and currently is in the planned state and that you do have to use the work-arounds to solve the problem for now.http://feedback.windowsazure.com/forums/169385-web-sites/suggestions/4250340-support-typescript-in-deployments-from-source-cont

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is because you haven't installed the TypeScript extension on the build server - it will need the same installer you used locally.

This will put `tsc.exe` into the SDK/Typescript folder and allow the build server to build your TypeScript files and check all your types.

Comment: We are using TFS on the web and do not have access to the build server since it is in the cloud and managed by Microsoft. We are using the hosted build controller which theoretically has Typescript installed. I guess we will have to use the suggestions posted by Suresh2. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I had to install Visual Studio 2013 RC2 to get TypeScript installed by default and get rid of this error message, instead of trying to download a package.
It can be found here:

http://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/download/details.aspx?id=42666

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I installed the update to `VS 2013 Express` and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

This message usually throws when you cancelled the installation of VS or changed the Typescript version or failed to install the Typescript SDK for the corresponding Visual Studio Edition. Download and install the Typescript SDK can get you rid of this error.

Here is the link for downloading SDK for VS2017.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=55258